# Find the index of the first space character?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, read-write

I've written functional code that will read and write data values to an arraylist. Though it returns everything, if a value has multiple words how can I exclude the first one?

```
  // 3 points
static ArrayList<String> Q2(String filename) {

    // You are given a file (filename) containing a different random phrase on each line. Return an
    // ArrayList containing each phrase, but without the first word of each phrase.
    //
    // Example: If the files contains the 2 phrases "roofed crossover" and "beneficiary charles frederick worth" the
    // ArrayList should contain "crossover" and "charles frederick worth"
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        for(String s : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename))){


            al.add(s.substring(9));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return al;
}
```

Heres what the grader says:

```
Incorrect on input: data/phrases0.txt
Expected output : [algae, blood platelet, charles frederick worth, convert, crossover, eye movement, ferocity, itch, lake albert, loewi, mountainside, peach, sontag, specialty, supposition, surprised endometriosis, testimonial, trial golden fleece, waterproofing, wrongdoer]
Your output     : [ferocity, peach, ed algae, wi, ossover, ry charles frederick worth, ised endometriosis, wrongdoer,  lake albert, ng waterproofing, d eye movement, mountainside, g testimonial, c itch, tal sontag, ive blood platelet, golden fleece, ic specialty, convert, s supposition]
```

I've gotten it to return some values back without the first string however some words are larger than the sub string can reach.

Comment: I fail to understand the logic of your code. If I had to do that, I wouldn't try to read all the lines of the file, concatenate them, then split on the comma character, then concatenate again. I would instead read each line, remove the first word out of it, and add the resulting string to a list. Then return the list. It looks like you haven't read, or understood the assignment.

Comment: I don't know how to remove the first word.

Comment: That's not such a simple problem, in the real life. But for this exercise, I guess you can just find the index of the first space character, and take the substring after this index.

Comment: I edited it but I'm stuck on the index part is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: You need to find the *indexOf* a character in a *String*. Reading the javadoc of String should be enough to let you find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is remove the first word stand before the space, then just use this code: get sub string of input string from position of the space char.

```
for(String s : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename))){
    al.add(s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")+1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest just to ignore the first item when iterating through the split Strings

```
    data = "";
    for(String s : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename))){    
         line = s.split(",");
         for (int i = 1; i < line.length; i++) {
             String data = line[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator");
             list.add(data);
         }
    }
```

Also you need commas in your output according to the comment.